# Discount rate interpolation in Quantlib with Python

Tags: python, quantlib

I have a question on the functioning of Quantlib when it comes to discounting. I'm experimenting with Quantlib for pricing term deposits which are more or less fix rate bonds. If I for example have an annually compounded discount curve and I have a cashflow date which is not a point on the discounting curve. Quantlib then will transform this curve to a continuously compounded curve do the interpolation there and then transform back to the relevant compounded curve. This will however not yield exactly the same value as if the interpolation was done under the original compounding method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import QuantLib as ql

from datetime import date, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def to_ql_date(d):
    return ql.Date(d.day, d.month, d.year)

def ql_discount_curve(spot_ttm,
                      spot_rates,
                      today,
                      discount_curve_day_count,
                      calendar,
                      discount_curve_compounding_type,
                      discount_curve_compounding_frequency
                     ):
                                 
    spot_dates = [today + ttm for ttm in spot_ttm]                  
    discount_curve = ql.ZeroCurve(spot_dates,
                                  spot_rates,
                                  discount_curve_day_count,
                                  calendar,
                                  ql.Linear(),
                                  discount_curve_compounding_type,
                                  discount_curve_compounding_frequency
                                  )
    return discount_curve

def Thirty360(d1, d2):
    return ((d2.year - d1.year) * 360 +  \
            (d2.month - d1.month) * 30 + \
            (d2.day - d1.day)) / 360

def discount_rate(x, spot_ttm, spot_rates):
    if x < spot_ttm[0] and x > spot_ttm[-1]:
        print('outside the range of the discounting curve')
    else:
        for idx, val in enumerate(spot_ttm):
            if x >= spot_ttm[idx] and x <= spot_ttm[idx+1]:
                k = (spot_rates[idx] - spot_rates[idx+1]) / (spot_ttm[idx] - spot_ttm[idx+1])
                m = spot_rates[idx] - k * spot_ttm[idx]
                return k * x + m

def create_df(issue_d, maturity_d, face, coupon_rate, today, spot_ttm, spot_rates):
    cols = ['date', 'year_frac', 'c_cf', 'face_cf']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    curr_date = issue_d
    while curr_date < maturity_d:
        cf_date = curr_date + relativedelta(months=1)
        year_frac = Thirty360(curr_date, cf_date)
        coupon_cf = face*year_frac*coupon_rate
        if cf_date == maturity_d:
            value_list = [cf_date, year_frac, coupon_cf, face]
        else:
            value_list = [cf_date, year_frac, coupon_cf, 0]
        curr_date = cf_date

        df.loc[len(df)] = value_list

    df['tot_cf'] = df['c_cf'] + df['face_cf']
    df['days_to_today'] = (df['date'] - today).apply(lambda x: x.days)

    # Discounting
    df['used_rate'] = df['days_to_today'].apply(lambda x: discount_rate(x, spot_ttm, spot_rates))
    df['discounted_cf'] = df['tot_cf'] / (1+ df['used_rate'])**(df['days_to_today'] / 360)

    return df

test_today = date(2022, 2, 15)  
test_issue_date = date(2022,2,1)
test_maturity_date = date(2022,5,1)
test_rate_calc_date = date(2022,3,1)

face_value = 1000
coupon = 0.05

# Setup QL
today = to_ql_date(test_today)

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today  
issue_date = to_ql_date(test_issue_date)
maturity_date = to_ql_date(test_maturity_date)
test_rate_calc_date_ql = to_ql_date(test_rate_calc_date)
settlement_days = 0
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
coupon_day_count = ql.Thirty360()  
coupon_frequency = ql.Monthly
termination_payment_convention = ql.Unadjusted
intermediate_payment_convention = ql.Unadjusted  
date_generation = ql.DateGeneration.Forward

schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date, maturity_date, ql.Period(coupon_frequency), calendar,
                       intermediate_payment_convention, termination_payment_convention,
                       date_generation, False)    

bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                        face_value,
                        schedule,
                        [coupon],
                        coupon_day_count
                        )

discount_curve_day_count = ql.Actual360()     
discount_curve_compounding_frequency = ql.Annual
discount_curve_compounding_type = ql.Compounded       
discount_cuve_payment_convention = ql.Unadjusted
```

So now Quantlib and the manual calculation is setup. If I now run with below input the manual calculation and Quantlib yields the same price and the cashflows are the same as the manual ones in cf_df.

```
################### CHANGE VALUE HERE
spot_ttm = [0] +   [  1,    7,   28,   45,  60,   180]
spot_rates = [0] + [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02] 

dicount_curve = ql_dicount_curve(spot_ttm,
                                 spot_rates,
                                 today,
                                 discount_curve_day_count,
                                 calendar,
                                 discount_curve_compounding_type,
                                 discount_curve_compounding_frequency)

discout_term_structure = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(dicount_curve)       
bond.setPricingEngine(ql.DiscountingBondEngine(discout_term_structure))

# Using QL
price = bond.dirtyPrice() * face_value / 100 
dates = [c.date() for c in bond.cashflows()]
cfs = [c.amount() for c in bond.cashflows()]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates, cfs), columns=['dates', 'amount'],                   index=range(1,len(dates)+1))

print(df)
print(f'Dirty price {price}' )

# Manual
cf_df = create_df(test_issue_date, test_maturity_date, face_value, coupon, test_today, spot_ttm, spot_rates)

print(f'Test dirty price {cf_df["discounted_cf"].sum()}')
ql_rate = dicount_curve.zeroRate(test_rate_calc_date_ql, discount_curve_day_count, 
discount_curve_compounding_type).rate()
test_rate = cf_df[cf_df['date'] == test_rate_calc_date]['used_rate'][0]
print(f'QL rate on {test_rate_calc_date}: {ql_rate}')
print(f'Test rate on {test_rate_calc_date}: {test_rate}')
```

The output will look like this:
dates _________________amount
1  March 1st, 2022_____4.166667
2  April 1st, 2022_____4.166667
3    May 1st, 2022_____4.166667
4    May 1st, 2022__1000.000000
Dirty price 1008.352288017911
Test dirty price 1008.3522880179111
QL rate on 2022-03-01: 0.020000000000002238
Test rate on 2022-03-01: 0.02

So far so good. If I now for example change the discount rate on a point where we have a cashflow, e.g. day 45 corresponds to 2022-04-01. Then everything adds up again, no issues.

If I now want to run a scenario where the 7d discount rate is changed to e.g. 10%. The cashflow on 2022-03-01 is now in between the 7d and the 45d point. So the discounting rate for 2022-03-01 needs to be interpolated from the 7d and the 45d point. Quantlib does this by transforming the discount rate curve to continuously compounded rates and then does the interpolation in this space and afterwards transforms the rate back to the relevant compounding method. The result is that the rate and price will not be exactly the same is if the interpolation was done in the original compounding space. The below code can be used to manually test the interpolation by going through continuous compounding.

```
# Test of QL interpolation
spot_rates_continuous = [math.log(1+x) for x in spot_rates]
cf_df_continuous = create_df(test_issue_date, test_maturity_date, face_value, coupon, 
test_today, spot_ttm, spot_rates_continuous)
test_rate_continuous = cf_df_continuous[cf_df_continuous['date'] == test_rate_calc_date]['used_rate'][0]
print(f'Interpolation on continuous rate then switch back to compounded: {math.exp(test_rate_continuous) - 1}')
```

The output will look like below.
Dirty price 1008.3441455893376
Test dirty price 1008.3440440963483
QL rate on 2022-03-01: 0.0726594108873293
Test rate on 2022-03-01: 0.07333333333333335
Interpolation on continuous rate then switch back to compounded: 0.07265941088732264

As can be seen above the QL rate reconcile with the manual rate when doing the interpolation in the continuous space.

Now to the question. Is this market standard? Is there anywhy to get around it, except creating one point for each day before creating the discounting curve object?